# What is the purpose of the second parameter in getline?

Tags: c, getline

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* buffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    size_t n = 3;

    getline(&buffer, &n, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

I thought the second parameter in `getline`, `size_t *n`, was to limit the number of characters read. But when I tried with larger input, it still read all the input. I searched in the man pages and online but could not find an answer. Could anyone explain it for me?

Comment: Reading the documentation closely mostly helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`getline` man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html):

Given `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`

> If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing
>   the line, which should be freed by the user program. (In this case,
>   the value in *n is ignored.)
>
> Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a
>   pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size. **If the
>   buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with
>   realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.**

Emphasis mine. In short, `n` is updated to make sure the line fits.

Comment: I read this but I could not understand the purpose of `*n`. Why do we need to pass it if the function knows how long the string is? How does the value we initialized it to before calling the function affect the program?

Comment: @W.Zhu: Let's say you know that the size of the line will never be bigger than `256`. In that case you can avoid the extra `realloc()` call. If the line ever gets bigger than `256`, then `readline()` won't blow up (or weirdly return `NULL` or `0` or something), but rather silently resize. So the benefit is twofold.